# Realized / noticed about a fact which is still true now + tense

Tags: grammar, backshifting

(1) I realized / noticed that people **will** avoid when it come to talking about money.

(2) I realized / noticed that people **would** avoid when it come to talking about money.

Do I need to backshift "will" into "would"?

Comment: People will or would avoid what?

Comment: Do you mean that typically people avoid talking about money? If so, you can say it like that.  Or, “People don’t like to talk about money, so they avoid it.”

Comment: "Avoid" is a *transitive* verb, which means it requires a direct object. Also, "*... when it come**s** to...*"

Comment: [correction: to notice a fact, realize a fact. no about].

Comment: I/you/she/he/we will avoid… *what*?? You need an object. *In polite conversation, people will* ***ignore/avoid the topic of*** *money* OR  *avoid talking about* money.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, backshifting is the norm. Not backshifting asserts that the verb is still true now. Backshifting doesn't assert anything.

So in your context, if you're making the *general observation* that people avoid talking about money, that means it's still true now, so "will" and "would" are both correct, but only "will" makes it clear your intent to assert that it's still true now.

On the other hand, if you are talking about some past time or event where people avoided talking about money, then you have to use "would".

Answer (score 1):

Talking about something you have observed recently;

> I have realised/noticed that people [tend to/often] avoid talking about money.

*Avoid* needs a direct object; you can't just say *people avoid.* You can include *will*, but it isn't necessary.

> I realised that people would [do this]

means that you realised something in the past that was true then.

Comment: Does the version with “would” indicate that that realization is not still true now?

Comment: The 'you' that realised it in the past didn't know whether or not it would still be true now (in their future). If you see what I mean.